# Tkinter window is not responding despite using after() method

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm implementing `after()` method to my code after finding out tkinter windows are not multithread-friendly. Back then I couldn't pop up my Toplevel with `threading.Thread()`, but seems like `after()` method is not working either. When you pressed the button, the Toplevel window (splash_screen) still gets laggy, you can't ever move nor resize it and it eventually freezes. I'm not sure why does it behave like this? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def splash_screen():
    global is_top_level_ready
    is_top_level_ready = False

    splash_screen = Toplevel(screen)

    frame = Frame(splash_screen, width=427, height=250)
    frame.place(x=0, y=0)

    label1 = Label(splash_screen, text='Please wait...')
    label1.place(x=122, y=120)

    image_a = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('dot_light.png'))
    image_b = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('dot_dark.png'))

    while True:
        if is_top_level_ready == False:
            l1 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=180, y=165)
            l2 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=215, y=165)
            l3 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=250, y=165)
            l4 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=285, y=165)
            splash_screen.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.2)

            l1 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=180, y=165)
            l2 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=215, y=165)
            l3 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=250, y=165)
            l4 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=285, y=165)
            splash_screen.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.2)

            l1 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=180, y=165)
            l2 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=215, y=165)
            l3 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=250, y=165)
            l4 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=285, y=165)
            splash_screen.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.2)

            l1 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=180, y=165)
            l2 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=215, y=165)
            l3 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=250, y=165)
            l4 = Label(splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=285, y=165)
            splash_screen.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.2)

        else:
            splash_screen.destroy()
            break

    the_toplevel = Toplevel(screen)
    the_toplevel.minsize(width=650, height=415)

def checkloop():
    global is_splash_screen_ready
    if is_splash_screen_ready:
        splash_screen()
    else:
        screen.after(100, checkloop)

def splash_is_go():
    global is_splash_screen_ready
    is_splash_screen_ready = True


screen = Tk()

global is_splash_screen_ready
is_splash_screen_ready = False

button = Button(screen, text="Button", command=splash_is_go)
button.pack(pady=30, padx=30)

screen.after(100, checkloop)
screen.mainloop()
```

Image sources:

[image: Dot Light]
[image: Dot Dark]

Comment: Any time you call `sleep`, it’s impossible for tkinter to process any events. You should never call it in the GUI thread.

Comment: @BryanOakley What can I use instead?

Comment: @duruburak notice how the `.after` method takes in a time (in milliseconds) and a function as it's 2 main parameters. It's for cases like this. Basically you can use `.after(200, <function>)` to call the function after 0.2 seconds. For more info look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801)

Comment: @TheLizzard I already used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.after()` in this way does not make the while loop (and `time.sleep()`) non-blocking.  You need to use `.after()` to replace the while loop and `time.sleep()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

def splash_screen():
    splash_win = tk.Toplevel(screen)

    frame = tk.Frame(splash_win)
    frame.pack(padx=100, pady=50)

    label1 = tk.Label(frame, text='Please wait...')
    label1.pack(pady=(0,10))

    image_light = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='dot_light.png')
    image_dark = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='dot_dark.png')

    dots = []
    for i in range(4):
        dots.append(tk.Label(frame, image=image_dark if i else image_light))
        dots[-1].pack(side="left")

    def update(i=0):
        dots[i].config(image=image_dark)
        i = (i + 1) % 4
        dots[i].config(image=image_light)
        splash_win.after(200, update, i)

    splash_win.after(200, update) # start the update loop
    splash_win.grab_set() # make it like a modal window

screen = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(screen, text="Button", command=splash_screen)
button.pack(pady=30, padx=30)
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolves your problem I put the popup in a only class started by a threading.Thread() and to avoid the `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"` error I put the `try:` command in line 32.

The `__init__` runs the popup and do the animation in a funtion in the class that is started in a thread. The edited code:

```
import threading # For threads
import time
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App: # The class 
    def __init__(self):
        global is_top_level_ready
        is_top_level_ready = False


        self.splash_screen = Toplevel(screen) # <---

        frame = Frame(self.splash_screen, width=427, height=250)
        frame.place(x=0, y=0)

        label1 = Label(self.splash_screen, text='Please wait...')
        label1.place(x=122, y=120)

        image_a = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('dot_light.png'))
        image_b = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('dot_dark.png'))

        App.splash_screen(self, image_a, image_b) # Runs animation



    def splash_screen(self, image_a, image_b):
        while True:
            if is_top_level_ready == False:
                try: # <---
                    l1 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=180, y=165)
                    l2 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=215, y=165)
                    l3 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=250, y=165)
                    l4 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=285, y=165)
                    self.splash_screen.update_idletasks()
                    time.sleep(0.2)

                    l1 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=180, y=165)
                    l2 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=215, y=165)
                    l3 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=250, y=165)
                    l4 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=285, y=165)
                    self.splash_screen.update_idletasks()
                    time.sleep(0.2)

                    l1 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=180, y=165)
                    l2 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=215, y=165)
                    l3 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=250, y=165)
                    l4 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=285, y=165)
                    self.splash_screen.update_idletasks()
                    time.sleep(0.2)

                    l1 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=180, y=165)
                    l2 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=215, y=165)
                    l3 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_b).place(x=250, y=165)
                    l4 = Label(self.splash_screen, image=image_a).place(x=285, y=165)

                    self.splash_screen.update_idletasks()
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                except: # <---
                    break
            else:
                self.splash_screen.destroy()
                break

def checkloop():
    global is_splash_screen_ready
    if is_splash_screen_ready:
        run = App # <----
        threading.Thread(target=run).start() # Runs the popup
    else:
        screen.after(100, checkloop)

def splash_is_go():
    global is_splash_screen_ready
    is_splash_screen_ready = True


screen = Tk()

global is_splash_screen_ready
is_splash_screen_ready = False

button = Button(screen, text="Button", command=splash_is_go)
button.pack(pady=30, padx=30)

screen.after(100, checkloop)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works too. But as far as I know, using `threading.Thread()` isn't recommended for tkinter windows.